# Count frequency of a letter in text file without using built-in dict data structure OR count function in Python

Tags: python, count, frequency, letter

I am working on a program that counts the number of words and letters in a text file. The program should also display the number of times each letter is used in the file. I have included my code for counting the words and letters. I need help with finding the best way display the letter frequency without using count or dict functions.

```
f=open ("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\romeo.txt",'r')

num_lines = 0
num_words = 0
num_char = 0


with open("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\romeo.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()


        num_lines += 1
        num_words += len(words)
        num_char+=  sum(len(x) for x in line.split())
```

Comment: What's the question ? Does your code work ?

Comment: Before finding the "best" way which is somewhat subjective, try to get at least a way. And then share it if it doesn't work and you can't figure why. I don't see any attempt here...

Comment: the initial f=open(....) is not needed and your indentation is bad. Does this even run?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work with minor adjustments. Try this:

```
number_of_lines = 0
number_of_words = 0
number_of_chars = 0

with open(r'myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        number_of_lines += 1
        word_list = line.split()
        number_of_words += len(word_list)
        number_of_chars += sum(len(x) for x in word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead

```
f=open()
num_lines = 0
num_words = 0
num_char = 0s

while str:
    str=f.readline()
    words=str.split()
    num_words+=len(words)
    num_lines+=1
    for a in words:
        num_char+=len(a)
f.close()
```